# Query to find co-located result SQL

Tags: sql

[image: Link to PDF of tables: http://i.imgur.com/XaZLxRQ.jpg]

**Question:** Get all player-number/slotMachine-number/casino-number triples such that the indicated player, slot machine and casino are all co-located (associated with the same city).

**MY ATTEMPT OF THE QUERY IS BELOW**

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PlayerNum, S.SlotNum, C.CasinoNum
FROM Player AS P, Slots AS S, Casino AS C, Plays AS Pl
WHERE P.Hometown = S.CityOfOrigin
AND S.CityOfOrigin = C.Location
AND P.PlayerNum = Pl.PlayerNum
AND S.SlotNum = Pl.SlotNum
AND C.CasinoNum = Pl.CasinoNum;
```

---

Than how can I get all pairs of city names such that a player from the first city plays at a casino in the second city. In other words, If a player lives in city X and plays at a casino in city Y, then I want the pair X, Y in the answer table.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  I removed all the extraneous tags.  Also sample data and desired results would help clarify what you really want to do.

Comment: Homework assignment? Please transcribe the tables and include them in the question text. +1 for  trying before posting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Dont' use that ancient join syntax.

Then: The request to get all players, casinos and slots located in the same city is easy. You don't even need the `plays` table:

```
select p.playernum, s.slotnum, c.casinonum
from player p
join slots s on s.cityoforigin = p.hometown
join casino c on c.location = p.hometown;
```

If you only want combinations that were actually played, the `plays` table comes into play:

```
select p.playernum, s.slotnum, c.casinonum
from player p
join slots s on s.cityoforigin = p.hometown
join casino c on c.location = p.hometown
and (p.playernum, s.slotnum, c.casinonum) in
(
  select playernum, slotnum, casinonum
  from plays
);
```

You forgot to tag your DBMS. Some DBMS don't support tuples with the `IN` clause, so you would use `EXIST` then instead:

```
select p.playernum, s.slotnum, c.casinonum
from player p
join slots s on s.cityoforigin = p.hometown
join casino c on c.location = p.hometown
and exists
(
  select *
  from plays pl
  where pl.playernum = p.playernum
  and pl.slotnum = s.slotnum
  and pl.casinonum = c.casinonum
);
```

Your other request is completely different and you should have written a separate request in my opinion. It's no longer "find same locations", but "find location differences".

```
select distinct p.hometown, c.location
from plays pl
join player p on p.playernum = pl.playernum
join casino c on c.casinonum = pl.casinonum
where p.hometown <> c.location;
```

Comment: "*Some DBMS don't support tuples with the IN clause*" - really? That seems to me as one of the most basic features. Which DBMS doesn't support this?

Comment: I think that SQL Server doesn't support this for instance. Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/728438/2. (Others that do support tuples are often limited when it comes to tuple expressions and fail on `where (a,b) in ((1,2),(3,4))` which Oracle handles easily.)